# Can't connect on service and get JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I trying to get simple json from URL. But I get exception on line c.connect(). I added permission for Internet in manifest.

Tried 5-6 codes, but everytime I get break on connection everytime. In debbuging I get response code -1 but going to final block on c.connect() line.

```
String result = getJSON("http://api.wipmania.com/json"); 


 public String getJSON(String url) {
            HttpURLConnection c = null;
            try {
                URL u = new URL(url);
                c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
                c.setUseCaches(false);
                c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                c.connect();
                int status = c.getResponseCode();

                switch (status) {
                    case 200:
                    case 201:
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line+"\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        return sb.toString();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    try {
                        c.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here is Log:

```
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.testapp.alex.testmaapp, PID: 2529
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp.alex.testmaapp/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp.SumActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.testapp.alex.testmaapp.SumActivity.makeRequest(SumActivity.java:82)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.testapp.alex.testmaapp.SumActivity.onCreate(SumActivity.java:51)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-28 13:00:13.111 2529-2529/com.testapp.alex.testmaapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: what is the exception? show your logcat..

Comment: did you make sure that you have Internet Permission in the manifest?

Comment: All is OK, last answer with Thread solved problem. 
Thanks, you guys are fast. ;)

Comment: yes any background operations or long running operations ex network operations should not be handled on main thread, it should be handled in background thread or in service or in asynctask etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logcat you posted suggests that you are trying to make this call on Main Thread and it isn't possible, so you have to start another Trhead; check this:

```
final Runnable connect = new Runnable() {
    Handler progress = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String response = getJSON("http://api.wipmania.com/json"); 
        progress.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do what you want with response
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and call in this way:

```
new Thread(connect).start();
```

Anyway there are a lot of libraries that make http request for you, in a very simple way.

Check for [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) or for [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

In my last project I used Retrofit, and it's very comfortable.
This is another [guide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en) for using Retrofit

Comment: Thank you, roccocullo, I will try. ;)

Comment: Thank you again, that solve my problem, I got result. 

Can you explain me deeper why I got stuck here. Or reference me what to read. Like I said I'm a newbie. :)

Comment: your main UI thread should do the minimum amount of work and any potentially long task that may hang your application should be handled in a different thread. Typical examples of such tasks are network operations, which involve unpredictable delays and would cause a block on the main UI thread.


check [Multithread](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/multiple-threads/index.html)


Thread aren't the only way to achieve this, you can use libraries as I said above or check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                    "http://bla/bla/bla");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already opened connection with `u.openConnection();` so don't need to call `c.connect()`.

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for more information:

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public String makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try {
            // Connect
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection
                    .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            // Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),
                            "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("result result result: " + result.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mahalakshmi, but I get again exception on urlConnection.connect(). 

Maybe I wrong on some other side

Comment: what exception , can u pls post tht and also chk on server side configurations